# `_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage1" doesn't exist`

Tags: python, image, tkinter

I'm writing a code and I'm getting this error:

this is all the nessacery code

```
import os
import random
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import tkinter as tk
def controlmenu():
    root = tk.Tk()
    frame = tk.Frame(root)
    frame.pack()
    path = "C:\\Users\user\\Documents\\Codes\\Python\\beathouse\\images\\controllermapping.jpg"
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(path))
    panel = tk.Label(root, image=img)
    panel.pack(side="bottom", fill="both", expand="yes")
    root.mainloop()
root = tk.Tk()
frame = tk.Frame(root)
root.config(bg="black")
root.title("menu")
frame.pack()
bgc = "black"

fgc = "white"
conrtols=tk.Button(frame,
                       fg=fgc,
                       bg=bgc,
                       text="view controls",
                       command=controlmenu)
conrtols.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
root.mainloop()
```

and this is the error
[image]

this is not the exact code but i tested this exactly and it threw this error
[image]

meaning there are the same errors

Comment: Change second `root = tk.Tk()` to `root = tk.Toplevel()`.

Comment: lol thanks that worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credit to Cool Cloud.

So the code says:

```
root=tk.Tk()
```

Well it needs to say:

```
root=tk.TopLevel()
```

Comment: It solved the issue but opens another window on startup.